# Drawing on the screen using solo

Tags: drawing, robotium

In my testcase I have to draw a line, or at least some points to imitate user's signature. Is there any way to do it, except of clicking on the screen by solo.clickOnScreen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use solo.drag() to draw a line.